# как с помощью регулярных выражений, в тексте содержащем одинаковые теги, найти теги с определенным содержанием

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как без парсинга, только с помощью регулярных выражений, получить из набора одинаковых тегов, теги с определенным содержимым

XML:

```
<tag>
    ...
</tag>
<tag>
    ...
    content
    ...
</tag>
<tag>
    ...
    content
    ...
</tag>
```

Результат:

```
<tag>
    ...
    content
    ...
</tag>
<tag>
    ...
    content
    ...
</tag>
```

наивное решение не работает:

```
.*?<tag>.*?content.*?<\/tag>
```

идея с negative lookahead тоже не сработала:

```
.*?<tag>.*?(?!<\/tag>).*?content.*?<\/tag>
```

интересует: можно ли такое реализовать на regex?
если нет, то почему?

пример в дебаггере:
https://regex101.com/r/ULZVO5/6

подобная задача с одинарными скобками место тега:

```
(...)(..)(...ABC...)(..)(.,.ABC,.)
```

решение:

```
\([^)]*ABC[^)]*\)
```

ссылка на дебаггер:
https://regex101.com/r/MyWevz/1/

Comment: _Регулярные_ выражения предназначены для разбора _регулярной_ грамматики. У xml грамматика _нерегулярная_. Именно поэтому сложно выцепить только нужную часть тегов. Однако, некоторые современные движки регексов давно имеют возможности захвата так называемых _сбалансированных групп_ (balancing groups), что позволяет парсить нерегулярные тексты. Они, я думаю, позволят решить вашу задачу. Но нужно знать, имеет ли их используемый вами движок. А главное, на изучение всего этого нужно больше времени, чем на написание кода с использованием нормального xml-парсера.

Comment: @alexander-petrov
возможно вы имели ввиду не "нерегулярную" a "контекстно-свободную граматику"? (по иерархии Хомского)... и да, вы правы. в моем примере все группы довольно сбалансированны (все скобочки аккуратно закрыты)... а что, рекурсии и субрутины в регулярных выражениях - это табу или плохой тон? Признаюсь честнно: я не очень хорошо понимаю как работает lookahead, но предполагаю, что подпобный промер можно решить такими средствами Поэтому и задал здесь такой вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Решение в данном случае:

```
<tag>(?:[^<]|<(?!\/tag>))*content.*?<\/tag>
```

[источник](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#explicit_greed)

[код в песочнице](https://regex101.com/r/ULZVO5/10)